# Gnome-log only have one logfile

Tags: gnome, 20.04, log

I can't remember what I did. Maybe I tried to delete some log files in /var/log/
But now my gnome-log can only display one boot logging.

[image: Logs]

Sometimes my laptop freezed and I reboot try to find something in log. And I can't find it in Gnome-log. Only last boot logging.